# What is wrong with string compare in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I have different xml's (for diff os), I am posting only relevant xml part for SunOs xml.

```
  <osname>SunOS
</osname>
```

This is fetched by jQuery

```
var osname = $(this).find('osname').text();
```

Later in the code when I compare, it always goes in to `else` part, I used `console.info` for firebug and attached a screenshot of my output

```
console.info("Before checking:"+osname);
if(osname=="HP-UX")
    console.info("HP-UX");
else if(osname=="AIX")
    console.info("AIX");
else if(osname=="SunOS")
    console.info("SunOS");
else
{
    console.info("Linux -");
    }
```

Screenshot of **Firebug** `console.info`

[image]

My question is why can't it check for `SunOs` or any other?

**Note**: I think there is a extra character after the osname, I also made a `xsl` in that when I check i do something like below, how can i do it in JS?

XSL code

```
<xsl:if test="$sunos='SunOS&#xa;'">
```

I have also tried `if(osname=="SunOS&#xa;")`

Comment: Thanks all for your answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the string is not actually `SunOS`, but `SunOS\n` (where `\n` stands for a newline). Use [`jQuery.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove the surrounding spaces.

```
var osname = $.trim($(this).find('osname').text());
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you've got extraneous white space characters, try this

```
var osname = $.trim($(this).find('osname').text());
```

and compare using this osname. Check [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a lot of white-spaces appended to your `osname`-variable - I experience that quite often when using XML. Try checking on `osname.trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you get a line break at the end of the string, as the end tag is on the next line.

You can use the `trim` method to remove whitespace character around the string:

```
var osname = $.trim($(this).find('osname').text());

console.info("Before checking:"+osname);

switch (osname) {
case "HP-UX":
  console.info("HP-UX");
  break;
case "AIX":
  console.info("AIX");
  break;
case "SunOS":
  console.info("SunOS");
  break;
default:
  console.info("Linux -");
  break;
}
```